Latest version of Flask will not run
flask run ends with the error ImportError: cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from 'flask'
Common question it seems, but I cannot find a straight answer for any recent versions of Flask. At present I am using Flask 3.0.3 and I have run pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade to get the latest version of everything. At present my requirements are
blinker==1.8.2
certifi==2024.7.4
cffi==1.16.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==8.1.7
cryptography==42.0.8
Flask==3.0.3
Flask-Login==0.4.1
idna==2.8
importlib_metadata==8.0.0
itsdangerous==2.2.0
Jinja2==3.1.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
oauthlib==3.0.1
pycparser==2.22
pyOpenSSL==24.1.0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
requests==2.21.0
six==1.16.0
urllib3==1.24.3
Werkzeug==3.0.3
zipp==3.19.2

Is there an actual solution to this? Every "solution" I've found comes with other problems and sends me in circles. Is Flask just broken in its current version? And if so, what versions of things can I use to make this work?

Are you using a venv? (Always use a venv with plain pip, or incompatible packages will get mixed together.)

You could be using flask run and pip install from different installation. You can verify it with flask --version and pip --version.

@Ry- yes I am using a venv

@BoppreH versions are: Python 3.9.6, Flask 3.0.3, Werkzeug 3.0.3, pip 21.2.4

But are the Python installations the same? You can also sidestep the issue by running python -m flask run and python -m pip install ... . The flask and pip binaries might be from different places.

@BoppreH forgive me if I'm too new at this to understand what you're talking about, but I don't think the binaries are coming from different places. The commands I'm running to install and run are: /usr/bin/python3 -m venv venv . venv/bin/activate pip install -r requirements.txt flask run.  So pip and flask should both be coming from the same install of python, unless I'm wildly misunderstanding something.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

venv creates folder with own version of python and pip but I'm not sure if it creates  own command flask - and it may still uses /usr/bin/python3 . You can check which flask to get /full/path/to/flask and you can open it - and it may have #!/usr/bin/python3 in first line. So better use python -m flask run or simply run it as python app.py
